# "Crave" as a verb vs "craving" as a noun

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verbs

Imagine you and a friend of you are having your lunch in a first class restaurant. You have never had lunch with him. You find the manner he has his meal pretty interesting and appetizer. Which one of the following sentences would work properly and correctly here to be said to the friend in our scenario:

> - The way he is eating is giving me [craving](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/craving) too.
> - The way he is eating is making me [crave](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crave) too.
> - The way he is eating is making me to [crave](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crave) too.
> - The way he is eating is [craving](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crave) me too.

I didn't find any useful link in internet in this respect so I decided to share it with you and ask about the acceptable structure here.

Comment: Your question title uses "carve" and "carving", but the question is about "crave" and "craving". These are very different words.

Comment: @RobK sorry for the typo and thank you very much for editing it. It is a common problem for similar words among learners. Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 1):

None of the above are correct and it's unclear what you're trying to say with this. I can't imagine the way someone eats giving anyone a craving. The food they are eating could give you a craving for that food.

You might say

- "His tacos looked so good, it gave me a craving for some."
- "I'm craving tacos."
- "His tacos smelled so good, now I crave some."

Comment: But I was not talking about a particular ethnic food, but I was talking about the way / how someone is eating their meals which makes you feel hungry and as they say appetizes you and you want to have some of that food too. @Rob K

Comment: So based on my original sentence and having a look on your respond I guess the only structure which works for my sentence is **"The way he is eating gaves me a craving for some"** @Rob K If you confirm it, then please tell me if **"for some"** is a part of the compound verb or it is optional to be used or omitted?

Comment: This idea of the way someone else eats making one crave the food being eaten is quite foreign to me. That's creepy. Around here, you would not watch someone that closely while they ate, unless maybe you were in a romantic relationship with them. 

But if you were going to say that, you could say "The way he is eating _gives_ me a craving for some", but it would be more natural to say, "The way he is eating makes me want some too", omitting 'crave' altogether. It's not a word we use a lot.

Comment: Whether or not you can omit the object of the craving from the sentence is very context dependent. In this case, I would not omit it. But anyway you say it, that phrasing honestly has sexual overtones. At least where I'm from it does.

Comment: Interesting! Then please let me know how you would say: **"I’m craving hookah. It really hits the spot now."** OR **"I’m craving a big bowl of cherries right now --- I’m craving a little bit of it too"** "@Rob K

Comment: "I’m craving hookah. It would really hit the spot right now." If you're craving a thing, it can't simultaneously be 'hitting the spot'. Once you've started smoking the hookah, you might then say "I was really craving hookah. This is really hitting the spot'.

Answer (score 0):

None of them.

You could say

> The way he is eating is causing me to have ***a* craving** for cake and ice cream.

The verb *cause* is better here because one situation leads to another.

*crave* as a verb usually includes an object: "crave (something)."
Honestly I can't see a relationship between how someone eats and the desire for something. Perhaps:

> Going to the dentist makes me **crave** ice cream

Comment: As Rob K mentioned in the previous answer, I'd like to find out how would it be posssible to indicate the following examples in natural English avoiding having sexual overtones like they say. **"I have a craving for hookah"** or **"I have a craving for a cup of tea."** @user3169

Comment: Perhaps some other patterns like "feeling like..." or "have a taste doing / having something" would work better here @user3169. What do you think?